# Display errors using VMWare Player and Remote Desktop on Windows XP

Tags: vmware-player, windows-xp, rdp, display, graphics-processing-unit

I've come up against a weird display issue that I can't seem to find any "fix" for.

When I first boot up my computer, everything behaves normally.  If I start to use VMWare Player and/or Remote Desktop, my desktop starts having some odd video issues.  The frames for some windows aren't drawn at all, if I move windows around rapidly, the area under where the window used to be isn't cleared (still shows artifacts of the content of the window), etc.  In some cases, the minimize / restore / maximize buttons aren't drawn (but are click-able if you can guess where they are).

I've tried the usual stuff - current drivers all around, using a single monitor, etc..  none of it seems to have any bearing.

If I try to disable hardware acceleration, it tends to crash the computer.

As I said earlier, it's running Windows XP, dual monitors, an NVidia en8400GS video card, asus p7p55d motherboard.  Not sure what other pertinent details are needed.

I would appreciate any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that VMWare tools has been installed on the VM containers? I know that I've had some issues in the past where the video is choppy at best until I get the tools installed.

Comment: Yeah, VMWare tools are installed.  The video issues are with the host, not with the VMs though.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar problems before on systems that are CPU bound. What CPU do you have and what does Task Manager show you about CPU utilization when you are having the lockups? My guess is that this problem isn't really related to RDP or VMware, but instead to anything that needs a lot of CPU on this system.